# Is it possible to publish instant app without associated URL?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

According to [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/08/streamlining-developer-experience-for.html) article (20 August, 2018) from Android Blog we can publish instant apps without associated URL:

> Today, we've made it easier to build instant games and apps by
>   removing the URL requirement. Previously, in order to publish an
>   instant game you had to create a web destination for it. The website
>   also had to be connected to the instant game through intent filters
>   and digital asset links verification.
>
> Now, it is no longer required to add URL-based intent filters to your
>   instant game. People will be able to access the instant experience
>   through a 'Try Now' button in the Play Store or Play Games apps, via
>   deep link API, and in the future through the app ads.

I've followed the latest Android [guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle) to enable instant experience in my game. The guide doesn't mention anything about required URL verification. The app works on local device, but when I try to publish it to internal test track, I see the following error:

> Your Instant App APKs do not declare at least one web 'intent-filter'
>   element with the attribute 'android:autoVerify' set to true in the
>   Android Manifest.

Is it possible to publish instant app without associated URL? Like it's explained in the Android blog post with standard intent filter below:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Probably Google has updated all guides but has forgotten to remove this check during instant app publishing? I hope so, because I don't want to create a web-site to be able to publish instant version of my game.

Comment: Not sure if this could be the reason, but do you have any other intent filters handling URLs?

Comment: @HassanIbraheem exactly! Thank you so much, my fault. The issue was with my custom intent filter that I use for firebase dynamic links. After I removed the intent filter, I was able to publish instant app to Google Play Console. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can create an app with instant experience without associated URL.
[This sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/urlless).

For an app with instant experience you no longer need the `com.android.instantapp` plugin unless you want to use dynamic feature modules at this point.

When onDemand modules leave beta, you can start using the `com.android.dynamic-feature` plugin in combination with the [PlayCore API](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore) to download a module.

Until then you'll have to use the `com.android.feature` and `com.android.instantapp` plugin to download multiple feature modules.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. My case is simple. I have only base module and no dynamic features. With Android Studio 3.3.x it is possible to just add the following <dist:module dist:instant="true" /> to the base module Manifest.xml file to make it instant. So I have removed installed and instant modules that were created based on previous version of instructions from Google.

Comment: Ideal video to understand new approach to create instant ready bundles - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9J2e5PYXNg

Comment: @Standy: Absolutely. That's exactly what I did for the Android Dev Summit app.

Comment: thank you :) One more small question. According to documentation instant app should be started automatically after click on banner. I have created standard advertising campaign for Android app on Google Ads. I see ad of my app during search in Google Play Store, but when I click on it, it opens just app details page, where I need to click "Try Now". The only way I can get instant run if I click on my own link with parameter "&launch=true". Is it a limitation of urlless implementation?

Comment: Appending the paramater is the way the app launch is intended to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create an instant app without associated URL, just follow the official [instructions](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle) from Google.

Many thanks to @HassanIbraheem who has pointed me to the right direction. My problem was with one more intent filter for firebase dynamic links with http and https schemas that I use in the app in addition to standard intent filter. It was used only for tests, thus I was able to delete it. After I removed the intent filter, I was able to publish instant app to Google Play Console without associated URL.